# QT combobox with multiple items at the same line

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, combobox

[image]

The buttonbox above has multiple items on the same line. It's a program called draftsight, written in QT.

[image]

The buttonbox with the red square is what i have, but i need more info on the same line..

Someone know's how to achieve this??

My current code to add 2 items in the same combobox line :

```
//setup combobox :
QComboBox *colors = new QComboBox;
ui->toolBar_color->addWidget(colors);
colors->setMinimumWidth(150);

//routine to fill the combobox with external data :
colors->clear();
Dialog_color().extern_toolbar_load();
QPixmap pixmap(15,15);
for(int i = 0; i<red_list.size(); i++){
     pixmap.fill(QColor (red_list.at(i),green_list.at(i),blue_list.at(i)));
     colors->addItem(pixmap, comments.at(i));
}
```

So in fact i need something like this :

```
colors->addItem(pixmap, pixmap, pixmap, "text", "text");
```

Is there a way?

Comment: I bet, no magic there. If you combine a pixmap from several smaller ones (via a little bit of drawing on it), it could be set as a "very long icon". You seem to be doing almost that, just fix your loop... or explain, plz, what those red_list/green_list are.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response,

To explain the red_list, green_list, blue list. This are the rgb color value's that user has set up in a tablewidget. The tablewidget data is loaded during program start and during program execution if refreshes from a text file which stores the user defined values. The dialog is not finished, but it's working as expected.

[image]

I have been thinking also about combining several pixmap to a long pixmap, but it must be a automated way to combine all rgb value's and other value's like linetype etc which each other. So how can i automate combining several pixmap's to one.. Hmm i have to think about this.

How did they do this in draftsight with QT designer? Default Systems will not provide the solution i think.

All input is welcome !

Edit, i found a solution.. Which can combine things automated when the function example is expanded. So far i am satisfied with the solution.

If qt can do a update for this. That would be nice. For the combobox a pressed signal would be nice also instead of using a event filter..

[image]

```
//setup combobox..
QComboBox *test = new QComboBox;
ui->toolBar_layer->addWidget(test);
test->setMinimumWidth(150);
test->setMinimumHeight(20);
test->addItem("test item");
test->setIconSize(QSize(100, 15));

//setup picture template..
QPixmap pixmap(100, 15);
pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
QPainter painter(&pixmap);

//contruct a picture based on rgb colors..
QPixmap pixmap_1(15,15);
pixmap_1.fill(QColor (255,0,0)); 
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, 15, 15, pixmap_1);
//load pictures from file..
painter.drawPixmap(30, 0, 15, 15, QPixmap(":/icons/edit-paste.svg"));
painter.drawPixmap(60, 0, 15, 15, QPixmap(":/icons/terminal.svg"));
painter.end();

test->addItem(pixmap, "combobox");
```